# The distribution of mean reversion time from the OU process

Tags: finance, statistics, arbitrage, mathematics, mean-reversion

I was reading the paper Statistical Arbitrage in the US Equity Market and I couldn't understand the figure that plots the histogram of the empirical distribution of characteristic time to mean reversion. Specifically, the x axis is the estimated mean reversion days, what does the y axis represent? Is it 1/speed of mean reversion? And how do they form a normal like distribution?[image]

Comment: https://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/avellane/AvellanedaLeeStatArb071108.pdf

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/249655/why-does-the-area-of-a-bar-in-a-histogram-represent-the-frequency-of-that-partic